# How get result in function as parameter of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

How to change data variable initialized in someFunc in processBefore function?

```js
jQuery.fn.someFunc = function(options) {
  var data = 1;
  if (typeof options.processBefore == 'function')
    options.processBefore(data);
  console.log(data); // need data after options.processBefore magic
}

$('#some').someFunc({
  processBefore: function() {
    // how to change data variable here???
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can `return` the new value from the function you assign to `precessBefore` and assign it to `data` within the plugin definition, something like this:

```js
jQuery.fn.someFunc = function(options) {
  var data = 1;
  options = options || {};
  if (typeof options.processBefore == 'function')
    data = options.processBefore(data);
    
  console.log(data);
}

$('#foo').someFunc({
  processBefore: function(data) {
    // some logic here...
    return data * 5;
  }
});

$('#bar').someFunc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Also note the line I added which deals with defining a default object for `options` if not arguments are provided on initialisation.

Comment: Thank you, but how get value of data var in processBefore argument Like: processBefore: function() {return data+5;}

Comment: You're already doing that - you're providing it as an argument to the `processBefore()` function. I amended the logic in the answer above so it now uses that argument.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is set to `1` in your example, which is a primitive, and hence, cannot be mutated. Instead, if you pass an object (which can be mutated), that should work flawlessly:

```
jQuery.fn.someFunc = function(options) {
  var data = {a: 1};

  if (typeof options.processBefore == 'function')
    options.processBefore(data);

  console.log(data); // data.a will be 2 here
}

$('#some').someFunc({
  processBefore: function(data) {
    data.a = 2;
  }
});
```